# Call Android notification from a java class npt from an activity

Tags: java, android

How can I start a notification from a java class?
I started the notification from an activity
but when I try to do it from a java class it did not work because it needs a context (this refer to my class context)
Here is the code of my function that starts the notification from an activity:

```
 public  void sendNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_camera)
                        .setContentTitle("Someone on your door")
                        .setContentText("Open the camera to see!");

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(CameraActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)      this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(CAMERA_NOTIFICATION, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You'll need to pass the `Context` in to the class that is creating the `Notification`. You can do that when you instantiate that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a paramaterized constructor having Context as argument for you java class and call it from your activity. How you calling your java class from activity. You might be calling your java class by making its object n calling default constructor i guess so like:

wrong way

```
JavaClass obj = new JavaClass();
```

Right Way

```
`JavaClass obj = new JavaClass(MainActivity.this); // MainActivity.this is` context
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the **Context** in the **Class**. In the code below I'm sending the Context to the Classes constructor:

```
public class SendNotification
    {
        Context context;

        public SendNotification(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

         public  void sendNotification()
        {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_camera)
                                .setContentTitle("Someone on your door")
                                .setContentText("Open the camera to see!");

            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, CameraActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(CameraActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                0,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)      context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                mNotificationManager.notify(CAMERA_NOTIFICATION, mBuilder.build());

        }
    }
```

Now you can create an Object from your activity and call the sendNotification method like this:

```
SendNotification sendNotification = new SendNotification(this); 
sendNotification.sendNotification();
```